# MySQL query with conditional SELECT arguments - Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql

SQL Query:

```
SELECT          
    IF(
       pu.userPayeeType='fiziska', 
       CONCAT(pu.userName,' ', pu.userLastName), 
       pu.userCompanyName
    ) AS supplierName
FROM 
    publicUsers pu  
WHERE 
    supplierName LIKE  '%Jo%'
```

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'supplierName' in 'where clause'

From what I understand, SQL query is evaluated and parsed "somewhat" from the bottom up which means that the WHERE clause does not yet know what an alias "supplierName" is and throws this error.

How can I make a conditional SELECT with regards to the column contents?

Database contents:

```
userPayeeType | userName | userLastName | userCompanyName
--------------+----------+--------------+------------------
   'fiziska'  |  John    | Doe          | 
--------------+----------+--------------+------------------
   'fiziska'  |  Joe     | Pie          |  
--------------+----------+--------------+------------------
   'other'    |          |              |  'Joes Company, Ltd'
--------------+----------+--------------+------------------
```

Preferred results:

```
Row #  | supplierName 
-------+--------------------
  1.   | 'John Doe'
-------+--------------------
  2.   | 'Joe Pie'
-------+--------------------
  3.   | 'Joes Company, Ltd'
```

Am I missing something with the syntax?

Comment: You can not use an alias from select in where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use alias in the where clause. You can use coalesce to get the first non null value.

```
SELECT          
    IF(
       pu.userPayeeType='fiziska', 
       CONCAT(pu.userName,' ', pu.userLastName), 
       pu.userCompanyName
    ) AS supplierName
FROM 
    publicUsers pu  
WHERE 
    coalesce(pu.userName,pu.userCompanyName) LIKE  '%Jo%';
```

Or even a simple where with `OR` between columns.

Comment: Not perfect (in the database userName and userLastName is also filled for company entries) but in my case it looks like the COALESCE will do the job. Did not know this function. Thanks!